# List<int> except(AnotherList<int>) not return correct results

Tags: asp.net, linq, list, ienumerable, except

here is my data:

OldAnswers : 
2
NewAnswers : 
2
3
4

```
int Diffcount =  OldCountryAnswers.Except(NewCountryAnswers).Count();
```

Diffcount is coming out as 0.

Is this right behavior of 'Except' ?

I need difference count between two `List<int>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int Diffcount =  NewCountryAnswers.Except(OldCountryAnswers).Count();
```

might be what you are looking for, this should give you a count of 2.